# what is wrong in this code . when executed it only shows the statement written in else statetment

Tags: java

what is wrong in this code . when executed it only shows the statement written in else statetment ....

```
public class palindromefunction {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        palindromefunction p = new palindromefunction();
        p.ispalindrome("nureserun");
    }


    public void ispalindrome(String original){

        String reversed = "";

        for(int i=original.length()-1;i<=0;i--){
            reversed = reversed + original.charAt(i);
        }

        if(reversed.equals(original)){
            System.out.println("thiss si a palindrome");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("this is not a palindrome");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it should be `for(int i=original.length()-1;i>=0;i--){` with a `>=` instead of a `<=`. Which you can EASILY find out on your own if you would have debugged or added logging for your code even one time.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `for` line code by:

```
    for(int i=original.length()-1; i>=0; i--){
```

You have written the condition in the oposite way.